# Sequelize sending multiple queries data to page

Tags: node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I am trying to display results from multiple Sequelize queries to one page using express. However, I am having trouble returning data from one in-model functions. I'm pretty sure this has to do with me not having a proper understanding of promises in javascript and also a misunderstanding of async programming.

In my report_ty model I have this function:

```
report_ty.getTopFreedomIndex = function(){
  report_ty.findAll({
      raw: true,
      limit: 10,
      attributes: ['Country','Freedom'],
      order: [['Freedom', 'DESC']]
    }).then(topfreedomindex => {
      console.log(topfreedomindex);
      return topfreedomindex;
    })
  };
```

In my controller, I am trying to take the data from that query and send it to the page in a JSON format.

```
var db = require('../models/index.js');

module.exports.index_get = (req, res, next) => {

  var topFreedomIndexPromise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    db.report_ty.getTopFreedomIndex(err, topfreedomindex) => {
      if(err){
        return reject(err);
      } else {
        return resolve(topfreedomindex);
      }
    }
  })

  Promise.all([topFreedomIndexPromise]).then((results)=>{
    return res.render('index', {topfreedomindex:topfreedomindex});
  }).catch((err) => {
    return next(err);
  })
}
```

I would like to create multiple promises and cash them out to variables that I can render to the page.

However, the code in the controller is not working because the console says there is a syntax error: unexpected '.' after db. I'm sort of lost at the current moment on how to go about doing this. I modeled this code on a previous project's code that used mongoose with mongoDB.

I can make it work if I move the findAll code to the controller but I was only able to run one query in that case. I would like to run many and leave the logic in the models.

Any help/suggestions/criticisms are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(db)`. Is your relative path for models correct?

Also, in your function `getTopFreedomIndex`, you should `return` otherwise if would be undefined

Comment: Thanks Abhinav. The db object is a collection of all my models where db.report_ty is my report_ty model. A console.log of db just outputs the sequelize connection details and the associated models.

Adding a return to that function helped though! I can now add a .then method to my fucntion in my controller and assign that to a variable. My next question is: how would I go about closing all of those out in one Promise.all and passing them to the page? Or is there another cleaner way to do that? rather than using the Promise.all? Thanks again.

Comment: Great that it helped. You want to call `getTopFreedomIndex` multiple times with different parameters?

Comment: I would like to call different functions such as getBtmFreedomIndex which would run a different query using another function similar to the one listed about. I would call them in the controller then res.send all the variables. If I try to store the function's return in a variable it's giving me an unfulfilled promise object instead of the dataset.

Comment: You are redefining the function `db.report_ty.getTopFreedomIndex(err, topfreedomindex) => {` , I guess you want to call the function here `db.report_ty.getTopFreedomIndex(err, topfreedomindex).then(..`

Comment: @AbhinavD I figured it out!. The promise variable should look like this:
var topFreedomIndexPromise = db.report_ty.getTopFreedomIndex();`
And the controller code should be:
    `Promise.all([topFreedomIndexPromise]).then((results)=>{
    console.log(results);
    return res.render('index', {
    topfreedomindex: results[0]
    });
    }).catch((err) => {
    return next(err);
    });`

Thank you for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I have figured this out! The code should look as follows:

Model:

```
 report_ty.getBtmFreedomIndex = function(){
    return report_ty.findAll({
        raw: true,
        limit: 10,
        attributes: ['Country','Freedom'],
        order: [['Freedom', 'ASC']]
      })
    };
```

Controller:

```
  var topFreedomIndexPromise = db.report_ty.getTopFreedomIndex();
  var btmFreedomIndexPromise = db.report_ty.getBtmFreedomIndex();

  Promise.all([topFreedomIndexPromise, btmFreedomIndexPromise]).then((results)=>{
    console.log(results);
    return res.render('index', {
      topfreedomindex: results[0],
      btmfreedomindex: results[1]
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    return next(err);
  });
```