# multiple SQL queries as one request on sequelize js

Tags: express, sequelize.js

Is there a way for sequelize to send multiple queries as one request? Or does sequelize already does that?

Below is my code:

```
const transaction = await db.transaction();

  try {
    await Resource.bulkCreate(resourcesTable);
    await postContacts(contactsTable, locationsTable);
    await postResourceTag(resourceTagTable);
    await transaction.commit();
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    await transaction.rollback();
    throw new HttpError(500, "Database Error"); // placeholder until validation setup
  }

const postContacts = async ({ contactsTable, locationsTable }) => {
  if (contactsTable?.length) {
    await Contact.bulkCreate(contactsTable);
    if (locationsTable?.length) {
      await Location.bulkCreate(locationsTable);
    }
  }
};

const postResourceTag = async (resourceTagTable) => {
  if (resourceTagTable?.length) {
    await Resource_Tag.bulkCreate(resourceTagTable);
  }
};
```

Currently, I believe the bulkCreates are sent as separate requests? I'd prefer if they were sent as one single request like how it'd be if the SQL strings was concatenated and then sent.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49999095/14662161) you can use an array of promises and then handle them all in one point, is that what you might be looking for?

Comment: No. That would still send multiple requests. Just almost simultaneously. I hope to reduce the network requests.